# Why sed doesn't replace some word in Jenkinsfile

Tags: kubernetes, sed, jenkins-pipeline

I want IMAGE_VERSION of deployment.yml to be changed for env.BUILD_ID as like the following.
If I run jenkins, it happens no error.
But, output.yaml has no change and get same with deployment.yml.
I don't know why.
Please, teach me .
Thank you in advance.

```
stage('Deploy to K8S'){
    withKubeConfig(credentialsId: "kubeconfig", namespace: 'dev'){
        sh 'curl -LO "https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.20.5/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"'
        sh 'chmod u+x ./kubectl'
        sh "sudo sed 's/IMAGE_VERSION/${env.BUILD_ID}/g' deployment.yml > output.yaml"
        sh 'cat output.yaml'
        sh './kubectl apply -f output.yaml'
        sh 'rm output.yaml'
    }
}
```

Comment: I can resolve this problem cause I remove several unvisible weird characters from first line at deployment.yml, where the characters isn't visible in vi editor, but visible by cat

Comment: Please share the contents of `deployment.yaml` so I can see why the rule didn't substitute.